# Error publishing .NET MAUI project: the target "_GenerateAppxPackage" does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I have a .NET MAUI project that was created with VS2022 Preview 2, and it builds without errors or warnings and works as expected in the debugger. Prior to updating Visual Studio to Version 17.4.0 Preview 4.0 I was able to publish the project as a sideloadable MSIX from within VS.

Since updating, I get the following error when I click Create in the Create App Packages wizard:

```
MSB4057 The target "_GenerateAppxPackage" does not exist in the project.
```

The error is listed against the MAUI project's .csproj file.

I've tried creating a separate new, default MAUI project in the new preview - this publishes ok and (as far as I can see) doesn't contain `_GenerateAppxPackage` anywhere within its files or project structure. So for now I'm assuming this isn't something new that was added with the preview.

I found some references to `_GenerateAppxPackage` on the web but they appear to refer to Azure integration. My project is a stand-alone data transformation app that doesn't even access the net.

I'm at a loss what to try next. I don't know what this target refers to, where it should "exist" within the project, or what it does. Can anyone help me understand the problem and/or point me to a solution?

**Update: 2022-10-28:**

- I tried deleting the project structure and creating it from scratch with File -> New Project, then adding back *only* the .cs and .xaml files. Publishing the recreated project gives me the same error.
- I also tried uninstalling the VS preview and re-downloading and installing it. Again, publishing the project gives me the same error.

I still have no idea what is causing this, or even where to start looking.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the Microsoft docs: [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows][1]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/overview

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Yes, I did.

Comment: Which step you face the problem?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I right-click the project in the solution explorer, select Publish, choose sideloading as distribution method, select signing certificate, select neutral architecture and release config, click Create. Build starts and then fails with the error I quoted.

A normal release build succeeds with no errors, so the build that the publish wizard is doing seems to differ in some way that I don't understand.

Comment: which certificate did you choose? I want to reproduce the issue .

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I had previously created a self-signed publishing certificate using the powershell New-SelfSignedCertificate and Export-PfxCertificate commands, so I used that. Prior to upgrading to preview 4 this all worked and I was able to publish a signed MSIX using the cert.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I've added an update

Comment: @AndyJohnson did you try to delete bin & obj folders, clean and rebuild your project, also when msbuild doesn't get the package reference you could try to unistall and install the nuget packages again

Comment: @LeandroToloza Hi. Yes I've done all that  Also deleted .vs dir. Also deleted all the projects, created new ones, and added just the iriginal source files. Also uninstalled and reinstalled the preview. I still get the error.

Comment: From instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder?view=net-maui-8.0) It was missing the publish profile step. Closed VS, deleted `.vs` folder, Reopen VS, a prompt for install something related to Desktop development and publish profile appeared (_Reload MAUI project_). Now another error pops-up but it's not related to this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned today that MAUI is [now](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-maui-visualstudio-2022-release/) in the mainline Visual Studio 2022 edition, I've tried using that instead of the preview, and I can confirm that the problem goes away. I wish I'd known about this earlier...

Answer (score 7):

I faced with the same problem at Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0 (net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0).

The simplest solution for me was be using the command `dotnet publish` directly.

At root of project just write in terminal:

```
dotnet publish -f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0  -c /p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this only occurs when "Target the Android Platform" is unchecked. Its a VS flaw that i reported to Microsoft. It makes the publishing profile unusable. If i need to create a .MSIX i have to temporarily check Target Android.