How to specify the output folder when publishing a MAUI App for Windows (WinUI3)?
I am not sure if this is a bug or it's by design and I need another switch but when I run this:
PS D:\Temp\MyProject> dotnet publish -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64 -o "D:\Temp\BuildOutside"

I expect to get my .msix bundle inside D:\Temp\BuildOutside folder but it isn't there. Instead it's at the default path: D:\Temp\MyProject\bin\Release\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppPackages\MyProject_1.0.0.100_Test\MyProject_1.0.0.100_x64.msix
Interestingly, the build process still correctly put all the artifacts at D:\Temp\BuildOutside but then the packaging process copies everything to the default folder and then makes the package:
PowerShell 7.4.2
PS D:\Temp\MyProject> dotnet publish -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64 -o"D:\Temp\BuildOutside"
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored D:\Temp\MyProject\MyProject.csproj (in 1.3 sec).
  MyProject -> D:\Temp\MyProject\bin\Release\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\MyProject.dll
  MyProject -> D:\Temp\BuildOutside\
C:\Users\lukev\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.3.230724000\buildTransitive\Microsoft.Build.Msix.Packaging.tar
gets(354,5): warning : Path to `mspdbcmf.exe` could not be found. A symbols package will not be generated. Review https
://aka.ms/windowsappsdkdocs and ensure that all prerequisites for Windows App SDK development have been installed. [D:\
Temp\MyProject\MyProject.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0]
  MyProject -> D:\Temp\MyProject\bin\Release\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppPackages\MyProject_1.0.0.100_Test\
  MyProject_1.0.0.100_x64.msix
PS D:\Temp\MyProject>

Is this a bug from MAUI for Windows or do I need to specify another parameter to specify where the msix bundle should be?

Have you tried this, Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with Visual Studio?

@LiqunShen-MSFT unfortunately I cannot due to this bug and only CLI works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74203992/error-publishing-net-maui-project-the-target-generateappxpackage-does-not-e

Have you tried updating the Visual Studio? It seems fixed according to the answer

@LiqunShen-MSFT that answer is 2 years old and yes I am [was] using the latest VS (at the time and now).

Oh sorry, I find the related issue, Maui Blazor App Publishing via Visual Studio for Windows platform is broken. Seems that it is not a MAUI issue and we recommend that you follow up the issue.
